# How to fix Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException after updating the Xamarin.Forms project from 4.2x to 4.4?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recently updated `Xamarin.forms` from version `4.2x` to `4.4` . After Updating the version, I got this Issue.

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException
  Message=Didn't find class "md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.ListViewRenderer_ListViewScrollDetector" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.Btrak.Chat-Bp6iWgfx-yVpLlz4qrZvYA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.Btrak.Chat-Bp6iWgfx-yVpLlz4qrZvYA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.companyname.Btrak.Chat-Bp6iWgfx-yVpLlz4qrZvYA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
```

Comment: Things you can try
1. Clear and rebuild the project
2. Update the Android support libraries
3. Make sure the the Xamarin.Forms library is also updated in any other projects that you might have linked

Comment: Make sure all the projects have the Latest version of Xamarin.Forms, Remove all bin obj files from all projects re-run and see what happens